# Using software to download shapefiles vs manual downloads

Tags: r, shapefile

I am new to geospatial analysis and am trying to self-learn about this topic.

I learned that the core of geospatial concerns itself with analyzing "shapefiles" - these appear to be geographic files that contain boundaries of different geographical zones.

I found this website over here which has different shapefiles for London UK: https://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/statistical-gis-boundary-files-london

Since I am somewhat familiar with R, I am trying to perform some of this analysis in R - for example, how to import the shapefile:

```
# Load libraries
library(sf)

# Set the URL 
url <- "https://data.london.gov.uk/download/statistical-gis-boundary-files-london/b381c92b-9120-45c6-b97e-0f7adc567dd2/London-wards-2014.zip"

# Download the zip file
download.file(url, destfile = "London-wards-2014.zip")

unzip("London-wards-2014.zip", list = TRUE)

shapefile <- st_read("London-wards-2014 (1)/London-wards-2014_ESRI/London_Ward.shp")
```

The code appears to have run without errors and warnings (woo hoo!).

Have I done this correctly?

Comment: Since you are beginning your learning trip, I recommend you to read this book: https://r.geocompx.org . Shapefile is a file format for distributing vector data (a geospatial data model). The other data model is raster, being tif, netcdf or hdf5 the most common file formats

Comment: If your research indicated "core of geospatial concerns itself with analyzing 'shapefiles'" then there's still a whole lot more to go. Many "geospatial" folks won't go anywhere near shapefiles, because they are inadequate for the analysis they need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try this maybe?

```
# Load libraries
library(sf)
library(leaflet)

# Set the URL 
url <- "https://data.london.gov.uk/download/statistical-gis-boundary-files-london/b381c92b-9120-45c6-b97e-0f7adc567dd2/London-wards-2014.zip"

# Download the zip file
download.file(url, destfile = "London-wards-2014.zip")

unzip("London-wards-2014.zip", list = TRUE)

shapefile <- st_read("London-wards-2014 (1)/London-wards-2014_ESRI/London_Ward.shp")

# Transform the shapefile to WGS84 format (useful for plotting)
my_shapefile_wgs84 <- st_transform(shapefile, crs = 4326)
```

Let me know if this works - you should get the following output:

```
Simple feature collection with 654 features and 7 fields
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -0.5103751 ymin: 51.28676 xmax: 0.3340156 ymax: 51.69187
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
First 10 features:
                         NAME  GSS_CODE HECTARES NONLD_AREA LB_GSS_CD              BOROUGH POLY_ID                       geometry
1           Chessington South E05000405  755.173          0 E09000021 Kingston upon Thames   50840 POLYGON ((-0.330679 51.3290...
2      Tolworth and Hook Rise E05000414  259.464          0 E09000021 Kingston upon Thames  117160 POLYGON ((-0.3084572 51.375...
3                  Berrylands E05000401  145.390          0 E09000021 Kingston upon Thames   50449 POLYGON ((-0.3038496 51.392...
4                   Alexandra E05000400  268.506          0 E09000021 Kingston upon Thames   50456 POLYGON ((-0.2699001 51.388...
5                    Beverley E05000402  187.821          0 E09000021 Kingston upon Thames  117161 POLYGON ((-0.246622 51.3992...
6                 Coombe Hill E05000406  442.170          0 E09000021 Kingston upon Thames  117159 POLYGON ((-0.2471369 51.409...
7  Chessington North and Hook E05000404  192.980          0 E09000021 Kingston upon Thames   50530 POLYGON ((-0.3183047 51.363...
8               Surbiton Hill E05000413  166.482          0 E09000021 Kingston upon Thames   50457 POLYGON ((-0.3131585 51.388...
9                  Old Malden E05000410  180.016          0 E09000021 Kingston upon Thames   50455 POLYGON ((-0.2450543 51.380...
10                 St. Mark's E05000412  137.578          0 E09000021 Kingston upon Thames   50450 POLYGON ((-0.3129779 51.397...
```

Note - you can check which version of R you are using. Here is the one I am using:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] leaflet_2.1.1     sf_1.0-8          dplyr_1.0.9       data.table_1.14.6 rvest_1.0.3      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.8.3       pillar_1.8.1       compiler_4.1.3     class_7.3-20       tools_4.1.3        digest_0.6.29      evaluate_0.19      lifecycle_1.0.3    tibble_3.1.8       pkgconfig_2.0.3   
[11] rlang_1.0.6        cli_3.4.1          DBI_1.1.3          rstudioapi_0.13    crosstalk_1.2.0    curl_4.3.2         yaml_2.3.5         xfun_0.30          fastmap_1.1.0      e1071_1.7-9       
[21] httr_1.4.4         stringr_1.5.0      xml2_1.3.3         knitr_1.39         htmlwidgets_1.5.4  generics_0.1.3     vctrs_0.5.1        grid_4.1.3         classInt_0.4-3     tidyselect_1.2.0  
[31] glue_1.6.2         R6_2.5.1           fansi_1.0.3        rmarkdown_2.14     selectr_0.4-2      magrittr_2.0.2     units_0.8-0        htmltools_0.5.3    assertthat_0.2.1   KernSmooth_2.23-20
[41] utf8_1.2.2         tinytex_0.40       proxy_0.4-26       stringi_1.7.6
```